# An honest and hardworking man / An honest and a hard working man

Tags: articles

> It is universally true that an honest and hardworking man is always a happy man.

Or

> It is universally true that an honest and a hardworking man is always a happy man.

Which of the above sentence is correct ? Honest and hardworking take different articles so do I need to use different articles with them or can I get away using article just with former word in such cases ?

Comment: I would say the first is correct and the second sounds wrong. The reason is that when you use two articles and two nouns (a hardworking man and an honest man) it makes it sound lime there are two people. You could also say "a man who is honest and hardworking is always happy (or "a person" if you dont want to be gender specific).

Comment: There are two rules at work. First, the option to repeat articles used with conjoined nouns. Second, the rule of *a* vs. *an*. The first can be decided based on context, but it is more likely that they are not repeated. The second only applies where you use the articles.